# Why does this ember component not render?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to learn the ember.js framework. I've written a component but it doesn't work (it fails to render). I don't know what mistake I've made. Please help! I have tried everything!

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>COMPONENT</title>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <div>
            prova
        </div>
        <button {action "Graph" data}}{{#link-to "Graph"}}>
            graph{{/link-to}}
        </button>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="Graph" data-template-name="component/Graph">
        <div id="BC">
            <div id="Gphic">
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`app.js`

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
   this.route("Graph");
});

App.GraphController = Ember.Controller.extend({});

App.AppGraphComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   actions: {
       Graph: function () {
           for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
               jquery("<p/>", {
                   text: i
               }).appendTo("#BC")
           }
       }
   }
})


App.GraphRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   module: function () {
       return data;
   }
})

var data = ...
```

Please explain where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got an error in your application template anyway

```
<button {action "Graph" data}}{{#link-to "Graph"}}>
            graph{{/link-to}}
        </button>
```

It should have either an action or a link, but not both. Try

```
{{#link-to "Graph"}}<button type="button">Graph</button> {{/link-to}}
```

instead.

Also I think your naming conventions are incorrect. The id for your graph template should be "graph", with a lowercase "g".

Is anything rendering at all? This is a great ember.js tutorial for beginners- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/